# How to merge two Instance/s and retain the classAttribute?

Tags: weka

I want to merge two Instance  (s) ,they have same classAttribute.
how can I do to merge them ?

```
example
dataset1.arff
@attribute loc numeric
@attribute ccom numeric
@attribute IsVulnerable {no,yes}

dataset2.arff
@attribute nIncomingCallsUniq numeric
@attribute nOutgoingInternCalls numeric
@attribute IsVulnerable {no,yes}
```

as U can see,the attribute named "IsVulnerable" of two Instance(s) has same value.
the target Instance what I want is like following:

```
example
target_dataset.arff
@attribute loc numeric
@attribute ccom numeric
@attribute nIncomingCallsUniq numeric
@attribute nOutgoingInternCalls numeric
@attribute IsVulnerable {no,yes}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
public static Instance mergeInstance(Instance a, Instance b)
   throws Exception {
  int m = 0;
  double[] newVals = new double[a.numAttributes() + b.numAttributes() + 1];
  for (int j = 0; j < a.numAttributes(); j++, m++) {
   newVals[m] = a.value(j);
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < b.numAttributes(); j++, m++) {
   newVals[m] = b.value(j);
  }
  newVals[m] = a.classValue();
  Instance newI = new Instance(1.0, newVals);
  return newI;
 }
```

FYI, this code works in my project. and for mergeInstances, just need to add a loop for mergeInstance.